# Traffic Monitor/Analizer for Windows Gateway

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, monitoring

one customer has a simple LAN with Win2k8r2 server acting as GW, DHCP and DC for all PC. So internet traffic from PC is going to that machine, then it goes to ADSL router from the ISP.

How can i check what and how long users are browsing? I was aksed to make oneweek reports of the most visited sites and PC names
like
PC1

facebook
gmail
google

pc2

gmail
nytimes

is it possible to made such repost using Windows Network Monitor 3.4? If yes, how?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can install [PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg) on the server and set up a packet sniffer sensor. Bind the sensor to the WAN interface on the server and it will capture all internet traffic and provide data regarding which computers, which protocols, which remote sites, etc.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to extract that sort of information from a packet capture, you're better off getting it from something with a higher-level view, like a proxy service.

If you've got a single server directly attached to the DSL, then it should be running some sort of firewall. Does that offer any audit options? If not, consider licensing Forefront (Used to be called ISA). I've not used it myself, but I believe it offers the auditing options you're after, and is probably the best all-round solution for a single server environment.

Comment: isa is not an option for me(they). But thanks.